# jQuery destroy and create timer function. How to destroy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, bootstrap-modal

I have put together some code to reset and restart a timer every time the user closes a modal window after pressing Save Changes.

The problem I'm having is when I open the Modal for the second time and press Save Changes for a second time, ***it closes but it starts a second timer on top of the first one. This effect stacks indefinitely..***

How can I change my code to destroy the first timer and create a second timer and so on, as needed, throughout the day?

Thanks for any help.

**Modal JavaScript Code**

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-modal1-save-changes', function (e) {
//$(this.form).submit();
    alert('btn-modal1-save-changes Click for #modal1 Event fired.');
//$('#modal1').modal('hide');
    $('#total-clock').timer();
});
```

**Timer JQuery Custom functions**

```
// Timer Custom function
jQuery.prototype.timer = function() {

    // Timer variable for setInterval.
    var timer;

    // Target html tag for timer
    var htmlTag = (this);

    // Integer increment    
    var i = 0;

    // Activate Timer   
    timer = setInterval(function() {

        // Always increment by 1;
        i++;

        // Output...
        htmlTag.text(i.toHHMMSS());

    }, 1000); // ..every 1 second(s)
};


// Format String Custom function
// Input type MUST BE INTERGER.
Number.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {

    var seconds = Math.floor(this),
    hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    seconds -= hours*3600;
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds -= minutes*60;

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}

    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the timer as a variable which can be accessed even after `jQuery.prototype.timer` has finished executing.
A good way to do this, is store it as a key in the `jQuery` object as `jQuery.customTimer`.

I've modified your `jQuery.prototype.timer` function to make use of this as shown below.

```
// Timer Custom function
jQuery.prototype.timer = function() {
    // Target html tag for timer
    var htmlTag = (this);

    // Integer increment
    var i = 0;

    // Clear old timer if exists
    if (jQuery.customTimer)
        clearInterval(jQuery.customTimer);

    // Create timer
    jQuery.customTimer = setInterval(function() {
        // Always increment by 1;
        i++;

        // Output...
        htmlTag.text(i.toHHMMSS());
    }, 1000); // ..every 1 second(s)
};
```

Comment: I see! And.. you've meant to call it customTimer or did you mean to refer to timer?

Comment: I meant to call it `customTimer` as it's a variable holding the result from `setInterval`. :)

Comment: Amazing. The scope of this variable is as far as jQuery.prototype.timer = function() {... is concerned, correct?

Comment: Yep! It's just a neat little way of making it accessible through multiple executions of your function.

Comment: I understand if it's too much to ask but, if I had an html tag called #total-clock, how would I append customTimer results to a total and then display this total on #total-clock tag?

Comment: What do you mean by append `customTimer` results to a total? How much time is remaining? How many times the timer has run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160473/discussion-between-vini-and-acidic).

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's clearInterval() inside function then call the function to stop.

sample

```
function stopInterval(){
   clearInterval(timer);
}
```